# Android Is it possible to change the appearance of the map in the google maps API

Tags: android, google-maps

I have been searching in the documentation and throughout google. I would like to know if it is possible to place an image over the map the api comes from to use something else as a visual but with the maps gps functionality. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two types of Overlays:

**TileOverlays** ([reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay))

> A TileOverlay defines a set of images that are added on top of the base map tiles. You can also use tile overlays to add extra features to the map by providing transparent tile images. You need to provide the tiles for each zoom level that you want to support. If you have enough tiles at multiple zoom levels, you can supplement Google's map data for the entire map.

**GroundOverlay** ([reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/groundoverlay))

> A ground overlay is an image that is fixed to a map. Unlike markers, ground overlays are oriented against the Earth's surface rather than the screen, so rotating, tilting or zooming the map will change the orientation of the image. Ground overlays are useful when you wish to fix a single image at one area on the map. If you want to add extensive imagery that covers a large portion of the map, you should consider a Tile overlay.